# multiply websites and different websites on the same iis server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, iis-6

I've got this kind of situation: I've got windows 2003 server with dns server on same machine. It is binded to adress for ex. siteA.com Now i want to add to this machine website which name will be siteB.com. I created a new website on IIS6 server with name siteB.com but I dont know how to set up a dns server. My primary DNS administrator created me an alias for my server and he describe it to me like this: 'site siteB.com is an aliase for siteA.com' and then he said that I have to configure my DNS server by my own. I've tried to add new alias in my existing DNS zone (for siteA.com) but it's binding FQDN name like this: siteB.SiteA.com which is wrong as I supose. Can anybody explain me how can I bind this 2 webiste to my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your litteral example of SiteB.com needing to be set up in DNS on *your* DNS server, then you need to create a new zone file called siteB.com.

Under siteB.com create two records.  One with either a blank name or "@", record type A, and either the same or another IP address of siteA.com.  The other record will be "www", record type CNAME, with a value of siteB.com, so www.siteA.com is an alias to siteA.com which is where the IP is defined.

In IIS as mentioned earlier, if both siteA.com and siteB.com will go to the same web site, then you should use the same IP addresses in DNS and make sure the IIS site has both DNS hostnames listed if the site requires host headers.  If the site doesn't care about host headers, and only needs the IP address, then you're done.

If siteB.com is a new, different site from siteA.com, then use a different, available IP address, add it to your server, then create the new IIS site with that IP address.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have 2 domain names siteA.com and siteB.com that you wish to point to the same location.  I gather this from your statement that one is an alias for another.

Doing this should be pretty simple.  In IIS6 you go to the properties of the website by right clicking on the website and selecting properties.  On the Web Site tab, next to the IP Address, select advanced.  Add an entry in the "Multiple identities for this Web site" with the same IP and port for siteA.com but use siteB.com.

That should get you 2 domain names pointed at the same location.

Comment: I set up the IIS server with this configuration before, but on my server I have got dns role which is set up to use siteB.com domain. So I think I should set up somehow the dns server to serve another domain (siteB.com) but I don't know how..